# Automate merging 2 image files

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-action

My scenario:
I have 2 timelapses, one of a city, 300 pictures, another one of stars, also 300 images. I now want to composite the stars into the city images. I know how to automate using actions so that it applies the correct mask to the star layer.

However, I need to know how to execute this as a batched operation, doing the following:

1. open city001.tiff from folder "city"
2. add stars001.tiff from folder "stars" as a 2nd layer
3. export into a new image, say "export001.tiff" in folder "export"
   then repeat with files numbered 002, 003 etc.

Can anyone help me with that? I only found solutions for adding different 2nd layers onto the same original image, but I need both a different background image and top layer image.

Comment: I think you will need to script this

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad damn. Although being no alien to programming, I have no clue about Photoshop scripting, so this will probably take me another week to figure out, but ok. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: The second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796764/from-photoshop-actions-to-photoshop-scripting) (the one about Script Listener) may be of help.